# TfidfVectorizer for corpus that cannot fit in memory

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to build a tf-idf model based on a corpus that cannot fit in memory. I read the tutorial but the corpus seems to be loaded at once:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ["doc1", "doc2", "doc3"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
vectorizer.fit(corpus)
```

I wonder if I can load the documents into memory one by one instead of loading all of them.

Comment: When working with large corpora, it might be a good idea to use a recent development version rather than a stable release, as `TfidfVectorizer` was overhauled for reduced memory usage and improved speed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can, just make your corpus an iterator. For example, if your documents reside on a disc, you can define an iterator that takes as an argument the list of file names, and returns the documents one by one without loading everything into memory at once.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def make_corpus(doc_files):
    for doc in doc_files:
        yield load_doc_from_file(doc) #load_doc_from_file is a custom function for loading a doc from file

file_list = ... # list of files you want to load
corpus = make_corpus(file_list)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
vectorizer.fit(corpus)
```

Comment: Any solutions if even the Tfidf vector representation cannot fit in memory?

Comment: what exactly is load_doc_from_file? I'm not getting this