# How to iterate TfidfVectorizer() on pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I have a large pandas dataframe with 10 million records of news articles. So, this is how I have applied `TfidfVectorizer`.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
feature_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(df['articles'])
```

It took alot of time to process all documents. All I wants to iterate each article in dataframe one at a time or is it possible that I can pass documents in chunks and it keep updating existing vocabulary without overwriting old dictionary of vocabulary?

I have gone through this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453855/tfidfvectorizer-for-corpus-that-cannot-fit-in-memory) but not exactly getting how to applied it on pandas. I have also heard about `Python generators` but not exactly whether its useful here.

Comment: Thats what the tfidfvectorizer is doing. Its iterating the documents one at a time and updating the vocabulary. What else would you like to do. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for the comment. All I want to reduce the iteration time for processing the documents using TfidfVectorizer. What Im doing as if now is  consuming more time for calculating resulted matrix as it process all df['article'] at one time I want it to be done one by one. Is it any more professional way to perform Tfidf on large datasets either through `chunks` or passing one document at time in pandas using iterable generators? Hope you got it

Comment: As I said above, it does not process all at one time. Inside [`fit()` method of TfidfVectorizer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ed5e127b/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L790), it iterates the series you pass and process it one by one, to fill the vocabulary and count matrix. It then processes the count matrix to prepare the tfidf matrix.

Comment: @VivekKumar so, what would the other way around to calculate Tfidf for `df['articles']` which will be more convinient for 10 million records?

Comment: Yes, you can speed this up. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26212970/5025009

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate in chunks as below. The solution has been adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754234/creating-a-tfidfvectorizer-over-a-text-column-of-huge-pandas-dataframe)

```
def ChunkIterator():
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(csvfilename, chunksize=1000):
      for doc in  chunk['articles'].values:
             yield doc

corpus  = ChunkIterator()
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
feature_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Comment: I am using the same code given above (by you) but why it is still consuming too much memory during the fit_transform process I ran out of memory again. Any idea

Comment: not sure probably you can refer to comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754234/creating-a-tfidfvectorizer-over-a-text-column-of-huge-pandas-dataframe. somebody did get a memory error there also