# Creating a TfidfVectorizer over a text column of huge pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I need to get matrix of TF-IDF features from the text stored in columns of a  huge [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), loaded from a CSV file (which cannot fit in memory). I am trying to iterate over dataframe using chunks but it is returning generator objects which is not an expected variable type for the method [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer). I guess I am doing something wrong while writing a generator method `ChunkIterator`shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


#Will work only for small Dataset
csvfilename = 'data_elements.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csvfilename)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
corpus  = df['text_column'].values
vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())



#Trying to use a generator to parse over a huge dataframe
def ChunkIterator(filename):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(csvfilename, chunksize=1):
       yield chunk['text_column'].values

corpus  = ChunkIterator(csvfilename)
vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Can anybody please advise how to modify the `ChunkIterator` method above, or any other approach using [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). I would like to avoid creating separate text files for each row in the [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). Following is some dummy csv file data for recreating the scenario.

```
id,text_column,tags
001, This is the first document .,['sports','entertainment']
002, This document is the second document .,"['politics', 'asia']"
003, And this is the third one .,['europe','nato']
004, Is this the first document ?,"['sports', 'soccer']"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method accepts generators just fine. But it requires a *iterable of raw documents*, i.e. *strings*. Your generator is an iterable of *`numpy.ndarray`* objects. So try something like:

```
def ChunkIterator(filename):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(csvfilename, chunksize=1):
        for document in chunk['text_column'].values:
            yield document
```

Note, I don't really understand why you are using pandas here. Just use the regular `csv` module, something like:

```
import csv
def doc_generator(filepath, textcol=0, skipheader=True):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        if skipheader:
            next(reader, None)
        for row in reader:
            yield row[textcol]
```

So, in your case, pass `1` to textcol, for example:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

In [2]: import csv
   ...: def doc_generator(filepath, textcol=0, skipheader=True):
   ...:     with open(filepath) as f:
   ...:         reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:         if skipheader:
   ...:             next(reader, None)
   ...:         for row in reader:
   ...:             yield row[textcol]
   ...:

In [3]: vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

In [4]: result = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc_generator('testing.csv', textcol=1))

In [5]: result
Out[5]:
<4x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 21 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [6]: result.todense()
Out[6]:
matrix([[ 0.        ,  0.46979139,  0.58028582,  0.38408524,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.38408524,  0.        ,  0.38408524],
        [ 0.        ,  0.6876236 ,  0.        ,  0.28108867,  0.        ,
          0.53864762,  0.28108867,  0.        ,  0.28108867],
        [ 0.51184851,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.26710379,  0.51184851,
          0.        ,  0.26710379,  0.51184851,  0.26710379],
        [ 0.        ,  0.46979139,  0.58028582,  0.38408524,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.38408524,  0.        ,  0.38408524]])
```

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for suggesting the alternative. I had thought of the same. I guess it was my lack of knowledge of generators that kept me fixated on data frames. I will try out both and chose whichever performs faster.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your answer here, it is definitely helpful! It seems like I am able to get everything except the last step. When I run result.todense() I get a memoryerror. In actuality, what I want to get is the result as a pandas dataframe and the code I have used for that in the past is: pd.DataFrame(result.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names()) but it too gets me a MemoryError. Do you know why? How can I fix it to get my pandas dataframe with no MemoryError? Thank you!

Comment: @mkheifetz well, probably because you do not have enough memory to create a dense data structure out of it. Why don't you just use the sparse representation?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivilagga, and how do you do that?

Comment: @mkeifetz that is what you already have before calling `.todense`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what is supposed to be the output here when I do: doc_generator(name of the file)? I am getting <generator object doc_generator at 0x0... etc) for some reason now? For some reason, after running your code before .todense, I get ValueError: emplty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stopwords

Comment: @mkheifetz it's a generator. That is what it has always returned. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried the same code as you have provided for training the tfidf vectorizer but with bigrams still I get memory error. The memory consumption keeps on increasing and finally I get a memory error during the fitting process of the vectorizer any idea?